# SSRS ignore a field result

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I guys

I'm having a slight problem with a report im currently writing.

So when i run this report it gives me a list of outcomes from a data source.
One of results is 'Closed' I want to exclude this outcome in my report. I cant exclude this in my SQL code as it doesn't bring back the null values. ( when no outcome has been given to a task yet i.e no one has had the time to do it yet i have set that in the expression to 'No Outcome'.)

So i want to know if anyone can edit my expression so it does not bring back the value of 'Closed'

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!OutcomeDescription.Value),"No outcome",Fields!OutcomeDescription.Value)
```

Any Help on this would be great sorry if iv not explained this well.
Rusty

Comment: I have managed to fix this using the sql code **AND ISNULL(oc.outcomeID, 0) <> 97** When i tries just using **AND oc.outcomeID <> 97** it removed all the null values and that is what i was trying to avoid. Thanks

Comment: Careful - IsNull may not perform as well as you'd like:  http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/adam-anderson/2010/11/18/How_To_Write_a_SARG-able_Query_on_a_Nullable_Column

Comment: Thanks for the link really helps me understand this query allot better

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you'll want to add a **filter** to either your dataset or your table object - whichever is most appropriate for your needs.

For a dataset filter, merely open your dataset properties, and look for the filters tab.  For a table, you'll need to go into the tablix properties.  Setting up a filter from there is simple.

Filtering at the dataset level will drop all of the filtered records before any controls on the report could access them.  Filtering at the object level would drop the filtered records from the control, but they would still be available to other controls.  If your report only consists of a single table, and no additional objects, I'd recommend filtering on the dataset.